# OAuth2 Clients and Grants

Tags: oauth-2.0

[2.  Client Registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) says:

When registering a client, the client developer SHALL:

o  specify the client type

but it is not specified how to define available grant types.

I can't understand how to define available `grants` for `client`. Can the client use all grants, several grants or only one.

[2.1.  Client Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) spec section defines `confidential` (web application) and `public` (user-agent-based application & native application) client types. `Public` client can't secure any client authentication credentials, so for such clients must be available only `implicit` grant or may be `password` grant for `resource owner` trusted client? But i'm not found such restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which grants are made available to Clients is a deployment decision to be made by the Authorization Server. In principle (by spec) there's no restriction on which grant types the Client can use. A typical way of working is that the administrator of the Authorization Server registers a Client and then assigns the grant types that are available to it. As you suggested, that can be just one grant, several grants or all of them (well, depending on the availability of a client secret, see below).

The Implicit grant by definition can only be used by public Clients because there is no option to authenticate itself as part of the protocol flow. Yet other grants can be made available to both public Clients as well as confidential Clients because they may be used with or without a client secret and as pointed out above it would be a deployment decision to define which Client can use which grant.

As an example of the latter: the Authorization Code grant is perfectly usable for public Clients in addition to its availability for confidential Clients. The public Client would receive an authorization code in the regular way and would present it to the token endpoint without authenticating itself as a confidential Client would do. Because it wouldn't offer any clear security benefits over the Implicit grant yet does require an extra roundtrip to the Authorization Server it is not widely deployed but it is certainly not prohibited.

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is another example of a grant that can be used by both confidential Clients as well as public Clients. The Client would not authenticate itself to the token endpoint but merely pass the Resource Owner password to get an access token.